# Java Spark UDF with input parameter as Map type

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I have hive table structure as below -

```
create table sessionize_data (
ip                  string                                      
cookie                  string                                      
userid                  string                                      
dattime                 string                                      
timestamp               bigint                                      
referrer                string                                      
request                 string                                      
useragent               string                                      
absoluteips             string                                      
xff                     string                                      
calltype                string                                      
url                     string                                      
unique_visitor          string                                      
referrer_url            string                                      
referrer_dqp            map<string,string>                          
dqp                     map<string,string>                          
params                  map<string,string>                          
events_subcategory      map<string,string>                          
session_id              string                                      
source                  string                                      
dwelltime               string                                      
traffic                 string                                      
viewdate                string );
```

Now I want to pass **params map** column in spark UDF as a parameter - I did it using following code-

```
spark.udf().register("populateUrl",
    new UDF3 < HashMap < String, String > , String, String, HashMap < String, String >> () {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;
        @Override
        public HashMap < String, String > call(HashMap < String, String > params, String url_type, String source)
        throws Exception {
            // some operation here
            return params;
        }
    }, DataTypes.StringType);
```

When I use above code it is giving type error for Map type.
Can anybody suggest how to build **JAVA spark udf** which accepts Map type column and returns Map type column.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this solved ? if solved  how it got fixed ? Me having problem  while inside UDF which accepts map throwing error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.HashMap

Answer (score 0):

According to the [_Spark SQL Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) the external type for `MapType` is `java.util.Map` so you should implement:

```
UDF3<java.util.Map<String, String>, String, String, java.util.Map<String, String>>
```

Comment: any advice on this UDF issue plz   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935600/writing-udf-for-looks-up-in-the-map-in-java-giving-unsupported-literal-type-clas